# Issue with Applet based application

Tags: java, applet

When one launches the application, It loads incorrectly and shows black boxes in wrong places, and some of the functions have words that are cut off
Its an applet based application. It works fine normally. Some user is experiencing this issue.
Any idea to solve this issue?

Is this something related to java issue in the user's machine?

Below attached screen shot is a part of the screen.

[image]

Comment: We don't need that image... We need the code to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Support your question with some code. Else it's very difficult to help. I'm assuming you're running it on a browser and not any other console to check in different systems. In that case,maybe you'd want to check the config of the different browsers. Modern browsers support almost all the functionalities that applets have. Hence using applets is pretty much redundant these days.